# Analytics - Total events divided by number of unique pages?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am using Google Analytics events to track keywords on my articles - not necessarily the best system I know but there are too many for variables I can't easily change it right now - and I would like to be able to see how popular each keyword is by dividing the number of page views with a keyword by the number of unique pages. Is there a/what is the best way of doing this?

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**

I currently have a system set up where every time somebody loads an article an event is fired for each of the tags/keywords used, with the keyword being the label. I can currently view my view count for each of the keywords by looking at the total events for each label, however I would like to be able to see which keywords are the most popular by dividing the number of times the event has been fired by the the number of different pages it has been fired from.

Comment: Are you talking about popular for the writers or popular for the visitors?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this I think the best option is to explore the GA API and some of the Gallery Apps. http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/

For this kind of specific scenarios you made need to pull data into Excel and do some custom reporting on your side.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/keywords) provides data that is similar to what you are looking for.  Under "Optimizaton" -> "Content Keywords", it tells you which words are used frequently on your website.  It tells you a "significance" for each keyword, which is what it sounds like you are actually trying to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this does not provide what I need. I need to track keywords/tags specified by the author of the article.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to track pages with keywords in analytics.  If you added more detail to your question about what you have tried, then others might be able to help you more.

Comment: I have added some detail - I hope it's clear but I'm not really familiar with the correct terminology.